# Is there an analogue to squeezed light for gravitational energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity

As mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_energy

"It is possible to arrange multiple beams of laser light such that destructive quantum interference suppresses the vacuum fluctuations. Such a squeezed vacuum state involves negative energy. The repetitive waveform of light leads to alternating regions of positive and negative energy."

Is there an analogue to squeezed light for gravitational energy? I.e. is there a mechanism where gravitational vacuum fluctuations can be suppressed that would lead to localized regions of negative energy/negative pressure?